# menu acordeon : div stuck in my list because of the overflow

Tags: javascript, html, css

I want to create a side menu and my code look like this :

```js
function opensubmenus() {
  $('#submenus').css("display", "block");
}
```

```css
#menus {
  overflow-y: scroll;
  width: 150px;
  background-color: blue;
}
#submenus {
  background-color: green;
  display: none;
}
submenus ul {
  float: right;
  position: relative;
}
nav {
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<nav>
  <div id='menus'>
    <ul>
      <li>
        <span onclick='opensubmenus()'>Menu 1</span>

        <ul id='submenus'>
          <li>SubMenu 1
          </li>
          <li>
            SubMenu 2
          </li>
          <li>
            SubMenu 3
          </li>
        </ul>



      </li>
      <li>
        Menu 2
      </li>
      <li>
        Menu 3
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</nav>
```

But I when I show my submenu, he do not apear outside the box... 
I want a menu like this : 
[image]
I need absolutely need the "overflow-y" because I have a lot of menu and I need to have a scrolling option. Did you know how to have this result?

Answer (score 0):

You have `<ul id="submenus">` within `<div id="menus">`, if you don't want the sub menus inside of the menu, make another `<div>`, and put it in that:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<nav>
  <div id='menus'>
    <ul>
      <li>
        <span onclick='opensubmenus()'>Menu 1</span>

      </li>
      <li>
        Menu 2
      </li>
      <li>
        Menu 3
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>

  <div>
    <ul id='submenus'>
      <li>SubMenu 1
      </li>
      <li>
        SubMenu 2
      </li>
      <li>
        SubMenu 3
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</nav>
```

Then to get them side-by-side, apply `float:left;` to `#menus`:

```
#menus {
  overflow-y: scroll;
  width: 150px;
  background-color: blue;
  float: left;
}

#submenus {
  background-color: green;
  display: none;
}

submenus, ul {
  float: right;
  position: relative;
}

nav {
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can change your CSS and use `absolute` position on the submenu:

```js
function opensubmenus() {
  $('#submenus').css("display", "block");
}
```

```css
#menus {
  position:relative;
  display:inline-block;
}
.main {
  overflow-y: scroll;
  margin:0;
  width: 150px;
  background-color: blue;
}
#submenus {
  position:absolute;
  left:100%;
  top:0;
  background-color: green;
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<nav>
  <div id='menus'>
    <ul class="main">
      <li>
        <span onclick='opensubmenus()'>Menu 1</span>
        <ul id='submenus'>
          <li>SubMenu 1
          </li>
          <li>
            SubMenu 2
          </li>
          <li>
            SubMenu 3
          </li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li>
        Menu 2
      </li>
      <li>
        Menu 3
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</nav>
```

---

<sub>**Bonus -- Quick Multiple SubMenus**</sub>

```js
$('span').click(function(){
  var col = $(this).data('color');
  $('.submenus').hide();
  $('span').css('background', '');
  $(this).css('background', col);
  $(this).next('.submenus').show().css('background', col);
})
```

```css
#menus {
  position:relative;
  display:inline-block;
}
.main {
  overflow-y: scroll;
  margin:0;
  width: 150px;
  background-color: blue;
}
.submenus {
  position:absolute;
  left:100%;
  top:0;
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<nav>
  <div id='menus'>
    <ul class="main">
      <li>
        <span data-color="red">Menu 1</span>
        <ul class='submenus'>
          <li>SubMenu 1
          </li>
          <li>
            SubMenu 2
          </li>
          <li>
            SubMenu 3
          </li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li>
        <span data-color="yellow">Menu 2</span>
        <ul class='submenus'>
          <li>SubMenu 21
          </li>
          <li>
            SubMenu 22
          </li>
          <li>
            SubMenu 23
          </li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li>
        <span data-color="green">Menu 3</span>
        <ul class='submenus'>
          <li>SubMenu 31
          </li>
          <li>
            SubMenu 32
          </li>
          <li>
            SubMenu 33
          </li>
        </ul>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</nav>
```